# Knockout: can't do conditional output within foreach block

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an array with X elements. I am looping over the array, and when I get to the last element in the array, I want to output an additional column

```
<tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
  <th>{{ label }}</th>
  <!-- ko if: ($parent.columns.length - 1) == $index -->
  <th>foo</th>
  <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
```

It is not rendering the final column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you want to compute any observable variable in view by javascript you need to use parentheses.

**View :**

```
<table>
 <thead >
   <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
      <th data-bind="text:label"></th>
      <th data-bind="if:$index() == $parent.columns().length-1">Hello</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5111/